# Get Color of movie clip clicked ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, color-picker

I want the hexColor of the movieclip which is clicked. My movieclip is a red circle with solid color. So on click of the red circle, it should return me 0xff0000. I use the following but I do not get the desired result. It only returns me 0.

```
trace(redcircle.transform.colorTransform.color.toString(16));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a [`BitmapData.getPixel()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel()) to get the color of your MovieClip :

```
var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
    bmpd.draw(mc);

// supposed that your circle is at (0, 0)
var color:uint = bmpd.getPixel(mc.width/2, mc.height/2);

trace(color.toString(16));  // gives : ff0000
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. To get the color of the movieclip this way, it should have a tint. Only then it works.